# Refreshing a jsp page periodically

Tags: html, jsp

I have created a jsp page in which I load a set of text boxes with values from the database. I need to refresh this page every 5 seconds. I tried using the meta tag, but it causes logging out. I am guessing its because the session variables are getting destroyed. Could someone please point me in the right direction? Thanks in advance...

Comment: which application server are you using?

Comment: Am using apache tomcat server.

Comment: The session shouldn't be getting destroyed because of a refresh.  Do you have some code you can share on how you are accessing the session?

Comment: In the previous page am setting session.setAttribute("email",email). That is the only session variable am setting. I am really not sure why its logging out. If I refresh it manually, it does not log out though :(

Comment: can you provide code ? As I have tried the situation you have explained and it works..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sample Code:

I have set session in previous page and i am getting it after auto refresh usin meta tag.

JSP:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="10; url=main.jsp">

 <%
    String title = "Welcome Back to my website";
    Integer visitCount = new Integer(0);
    String visitCountKey = new String("visitCount");
    String userIDKey = new String("userID");
    String userID = new String("No User");

    if (session.getAttribute(userIDKey)!=null){
        System.out.println("Found Session Attribute");
       visitCount = (Integer) session.getAttribute(visitCountKey);
        if(visitCount!=null)
            visitCount = visitCount + 1;
        else 
            visitCount = 1;
        userID = (String)session.getAttribute(userIDKey);
        session.setAttribute(visitCountKey,  visitCount);
    } else {
        System.out.println("New Session");
        title = "Welcome to my website"; 
        session.setAttribute(userIDKey, userID);
        session.setAttribute(visitCountKey,  visitCount);
    }
```

%>

```
Hi <%= userID%> &nbsp; <%=title %>
Visit Count <%= visitCount%>
```

Comment: Thank you. Can you suggest a method how we can resolve this? Will ajax calls solve this?

Comment: yes, this is working for every other page other than the home page -which I enter right after I log in

Comment: Paste Code for set sessions & get sessions in the questions.. There is no other way to help you.